# How to bubble sort objects in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object

I have a bit a of a problem. I'm trying to sort an array with objects in it. The objects are bottles with names, prices and types. The user makes a choice, which bottle he/she want's to add to the array.

For the assignment we have to use bubble sort. I've made it work, except it only sorts the price. The entire object doesn't switch place just the price itself. So if Coca-Cola's original price was 13 in list, after bubble sort it's 10. So the only thing that changes or gets sorted is the price and not the entire object, if that makes any sense.

```
public void sort_sodas()
{
    int max = sodas.Length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        int nrLeft = max - i;

        for (int j = 0; j < nrLeft; j++)
        {
            if (sodas[j+1] == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (sodas[j].Price > sodas[j+1].Price)
            {
                int temp = sodas[j].Price;
                sodas[j].Price = sodas[j + 1].Price;
                sodas[j + 1].Price = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below an image of before and after bubble sort:

[image]

Comment: obviously you should swap whole object not only price ..  `var temp = sodas[j]; sodas[j] = ...` and so on

Comment: But your code only changes the `Price`. What type of objects are in the `sodas`? Can you swap whole objects instead?

Comment: I've tried to swap the entire object and not just the price. I cant make it work, if anyone could show me how it's done, I would be grateful. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change prices of objects here:

```
else if (sodas[j].Price > sodas[j + 1].Price)
{
    int temp = sodas[j].Price;
    sodas[j].Price = sodas[j + 1].Price;
    sodas[j + 1].Price = temp;
}
```

You should change object positions:

```
else if (sodas[j].Price > sodas[j + 1].Price)
{
    var tempObject = sodas[j];
    sodas[j] = sodas[j + 1];
    sodas[j + 1] = tempObject;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user11131093, you are welcome